# Why rounding errors when casting float(53) to VARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: t-sql, floating-accuracy

I understand that float numbers are inaccurate. [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

My question is why a simple cast to a `varchar(max)` will sometimes lose precision, and why this seems to happen only when there are five digits before the point.

For instance when the float has more than four digits before the point. The second digit after the decimal is sometimes lost. For instance.

```
declare @p FLOAT(53)
set @p=10080.12
select @p,cast(@p as VARCHAR(max))
```

> 10080.12       10080.1

Here the float has four digits before the point and it works.

```
declare @q float(53)
set @q=9980.12
select @q,cast(@q as VARCHAR(max))
```

> 9980.12        9980.12

I note that [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) recommends using STR and not CAST, but I would still like to understand *why* this is happening. And anyway Microsoft's recommendation does not say that precision will be lost.

> When you want to convert from float or real to character data, using the STR string
> function is usually more useful than CAST( ). This is because STR enables
> more control over formatting. For more information, see STR (Transact-SQL) and
> Functions (Transact-SQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#float-and-real-styles) for `CAST` and `CONVERT` :

> #### Syntax
>
> `CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )`
>
> `CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )`
>
> ...
>
> #### float and real styles
>
> For a float or real expression, style can have one of the values shown in the following table. Other values are processed as 0.
>
> | Value | Output |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 (default) | A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate. |
> | 1 | Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation. |
> | 2 | Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation. |

So default 0 style is used, which is 6 digits max. Which seems unavoidable with `CAST`.

To use more digits one may use`STR` function as mentioned in the question. Or `CONVERT` with a non-zero style parameter (this will use scientific notation), like:

> CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), @q, 1)

Comment: Much appreciated! I note however that using CONVERT with a non-zero style will always result in scientific notation, which may not always be desired.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, updated answer mentioning it